# How to ignore linearly correlated variables introduced by factor reference cell coding

Tags: r, glm

Assume I have a dataset containing two categorical predictor variables (a,b) and a binary target (y) variable.

```
> df <- data.frame(
>  a = factor(c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat1","cat2")), 
>  b = factor(c("cat1","cat1","cat3","cat2","cat2")), 
>  y = factor(c(T,F,T,F,T))
> )
```

The following logical relations exist in the data:

```
if (a = cat3) then (b = cat3 and y = true)
else if (a = b) then (y = true) else y = false
```

I want to use `glm` to build a model for my dataset.
`glm` will automatically apply reference cell coding on my categorical variables a and b. It will also take care of finding the right number of codes for each factor variable, so that no `alias` variables are introduced (explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70700/87383)).

However it can happen, as for the dataset above, that a linear relationship exists between one reference code generated for variable a and one reference code of variable b.

See the output of my model:

```
> model <- glm(y ~ ., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=df)
> summary(model)
...
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  1.965e-16  1.732e+00   0.000    1.000
acat2       -2.396e-16  2.000e+00   0.000    1.000
acat3        1.857e+01  6.523e+03   0.003    0.998
bcat2        0.000e+00  2.000e+00   0.000    1.000
bcat3               NA         NA      NA       NA # <- get rid of this?
```

How should I handle this case?
Is there a way to tell glm to omit some of the generated reference codes?
In the real problem my `"cat3"` value corresponds to `NA`. I have two meaningful factor variables which are `NA` in exactly the same instances of my dataset.

**EDIT:**

The checked answer solves the question, however, in this specific case the singularities can simply be ignored as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: Thanks for raising the question. I was not sure if singularities might have any negative impact on the model (or e.g. algorithm convergence speed), so if I understand you correctly, I can simply ignore those singularities and use the produced model for predictions as is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments made under the question are pertinent but it may still be useful to try eliminating the NA model matrix columns so that you can compare it to not doing such elimition in order to satisfy yourself regarding the equivalence.

In particular, you could run `glm` twice removing the redundant model matrix columns on the second run:

```
model <- glm(y ~ ., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=df) # as in question

mm <- model.matrix(model)[, !is.na(coef(model)) ]
df0 <- data.frame(y = df$y, mm[, -1])
update(model, data = df0)
```

giving:

```
Call:  glm(formula = y ~ ., family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df0)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        acat2        acat3        bcat2  
  1.965e-16   -2.396e-16    1.857e+01    0.000e+00  

Degrees of Freedom: 4 Total (i.e. Null);  1 Residual
Null Deviance:      6.73 
Residual Deviance: 5.545        AIC: 13.55
```

Note that if you don't want to use the fact that we know that the response is named y then we could extract the response and its name replacing the assignment to `df0` above with:

```
df0 <- data.frame(model.response(model.frame(model)), mm[, -1])
names(df0)[1] <- as.character(attr(terms(model), "variables")[[2]])
```

Comment: I didn't know model.matrix. Is that also used by glm internally? If my df contains some more numerical variables (to be kept as is) I would have to exclude those from the model.matrix right?

Comment: As I understand the question you want to exclude the model matrix columns that have NA coefficients and the above code should do it regardless of the type of column in the model frame.